# Import data from async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, import

I'm dealing with a project that uses AWS Cognito. There are some configuration params that needs to be fetched from server with an API call. I keep the API call in a config.js file and use async/await to get response from server like  this

```
const getCognitoConfigs = async () => {
const res = await axios.get(`${apiurl.apiurl}/logininfo`);
console.log(res.data);
return res.data;
}; 

export default getCognitoConfigs;
```

And in my index.js (where I set up Cognito), I import the function from config.js file

```
import getCognitoConfigs from "./config";
const configs = getCognitoConfigs();

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        mandatorySignIn: true,
        region: configs.cognito.region,
        userPoolId: configs.cognito.user_pool,
        userPoolWebClientId: configs.cognito.app_client_id
    }
});
```

The problem is async await does not stop the program execution so I'm getting 'configs' as undefined. Are there anyways that I can make the app stop until the api call has resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Can you await `getCognitoConfigs()` in index.js by wrapping it in an (anonymous) async function? Otherwise you could retrieve the results of the `getCognitoConfigs()` promise using `.then()`;

Comment: I've tried doing this and still gets an error ('configs' as null) 
let configs = null;
(async function() {
    const res = await getCognitoConfigs();
    console.log(res);
    configs = res;
})();

Comment: Are you running `Amplify.configure` in the same anonymous async function? If you don't, `configs` will simply be `null` as the async function only gets executed after you run `Amplify.configure`.

Comment: ah yes, I put the Amplify stuff out of the anonymous function. Changed that and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use async/await, you have to wrap index.js in an asynchronous function and add

```
await getCognitoConfigs();
```

or you can use promise like

```
getCognitoConfigs().then(res => Amplify.configure({...}))
```